# Is it possible to alter this table?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my previous app release I had a table created like:

```
public static final String CREATE_DATABASE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
        + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + " TEXT, "
        + COLUMN_NAME_LOGIN + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_NAME_NOTES
        + " TEXT);";
```

In current version I have a table created like:

```
public static final String CREATE_DATABASE = "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " USING fts3 "
        + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + " TEXT, "
        + COLUMN_NAME_LOGIN + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_NAME_NOTES
        + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_NAME_FAV + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " + KEY_WORD + ");";
```

So now it is `VIRTUAL`, created `USING fts3` and added two new columns `COLUMN_NAME_FAV` and `KEY_WORD`.

Is that possible to ALTER the table somehow on upgrade? If not, what shall I do so users don't lose their data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to run a simple alter command that will convert a regular table to a `VIRTUAL` table.

Instead of that you should:

1. Load the data from the table into the memory / copy the table.
2. `DROP` the old table.
3. `CREATE` the new table.
4. Populate the new table with the data from step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is safe to add new columns to existing table as long as they are nullable and/or have default values. Why don't you create a copy of your existing table and try to alter it (a copy) to check what happens.
P.S. You may have to set few DB flags to allow alter tables while DB is running.